# NodeJs Encrypting Passwords

Tags: node.js, node-crypto

```
var password = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data.password).digest('base64');
var salt = md5(uniqid() + 'secret');
```

I want to reverse the hash

For example I got:

```
dorZJ+jKH8z29WYXf/+NOiuQYpj3UZDPdr05mj3bN4s=
```

For babylone as a password!

Comment: You cannot reverse hashes.

Comment: This is not how hashes work. They are one-way.

Comment: Off topic: But you just revealed your password. Never do that! :P :D

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

the point of a hash is that it is not reversible, but with the same input it will always give the same output.

To verify the hash against a password, you just have to generate a hash from that password and compare the two.

Comment: I Mean how i Can get The SHA256 Hash !

Comment: @user7661923 `var password = ......`, so it's now in the variable `password`, base64-encoded

Comment: Just using a hash function even with a salt is not sufficiently secure, see the comment to the question fr details.